# Stop certain bits of code from running when page actions to itself

Tags: php, html

Right now I have a form actioning to itself. There is some code the checks if the user is meant to be there. Is there a way to stop the script from running certain sections of code if it was actioned to itself after pressing submit.

I was thinking about using a SESSION variable to check against but I've gotten all muddle in my head :p

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the code you're working with? Is your form using POST/GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. If you're self-submitting form actions, just check if `$_POST` is empty (assuming you're POST'ing to your form)

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
...
}
```

When I do PHP I use an input-element in my form template, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /></td>
```

... and in the PHP page, I check if the POST was self-submitted like so:

```
// if page is not submitted to itself echo the form
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
...
}
```

This is not secure though. If you want to reap the full benefits of self-submitting, you should try to counter [Cross-site request forgery (XSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) by challenging the client with a random token, and asking the client to repeat it.

Like embedded a hidden input in your form something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<? echo $NONCE_VALUE; ?>" />
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes I am using the if isset submit. The first part is what i needed :) Basically when it actions to itself, the whole page redirects. At the start of the script there is an if statement getting a value from a db. When after loading the script the first time changes the value in the db. Actioning to itself and therefore running the script again causes it to redirect as the code is to check for use validity in terms of where they've come from.